# document.getElementById('elementid').etc or elementid.etc?

Tags: javascript, html

Instead of

#### HTML

```
<input type='text' id='username'>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
var username = document.getElementById('username'); <!-- IS IT REQUIRED? -->
username.classList.add('class');
```

Can I just do?

#### HTML

```
<input type='text' id='username'>
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```
username.classList.add('class');
```

Using the element without storing it's id in a variable.

It seems to work fine, I guess it just takes the element id directly and there's no need of declaring any variable, if so, is it all the same or is it any prejudicial to my script doing one way or the other?

**EDIT**: Hey guys I'll edit this to clarify a little more.

I know that by storing the value I wouldn't have to write document.getElement....... all the time.

The question is about **using the stored value** or **never store at all** just using the element id directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just use this element once, you can use:

```
document.getElementById('username').classList.add('class');
```

If you use this element many times, you should store it into a variable to use, because it helps you write faster. You just need to guarantee that nothing will override this variable.

For should or shouldn't use id directly. The answer is NO. There are many reasons: if the element with specific id doesn't exist, then getElementById will return null, but using id directly => error; you can use id with some symbols such as -, +,... so in this case, you can call them by getElementById; you cannot use id directly in this case; for security...

Comment: The last paragraph answers the question and clarifies a lot, ty for your input.

Comment: Not just for writing code fast, it also executes significantly faster.
To a compiler, this 
document.getElementById('username').classList.add('class');
is the same as
var temp=document.getElementById('username');
temp.classList.add('class');
It automatically makes a temporary variable for you.  But each time you do this, it makes another variable, and it has to read the DOM again, which has a high time cost.

Comment: Yes, more significant if we use it more and more times.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do this because username is a global variable.

But this is not a good Solution, because other plug´s could override this variable. document.getElementByID is the secure way...

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('username').classList.add('class');
```

Will work, but if you need to use the element twice, you should store it first so it can execute faster.

Comment: Copy and pasted... yes I did lol.
Serves me right for answering questions before I've had morning coffee